# issue with setting expiry time of cookie in PHP header() vs setcookie()

Tags: php, cookies

I want to use **header()** function to set a cookie with 30 day expiry time as shown below:

```
$exptime=time()+30*24*60*60;
header("Set-Cookie: __try1=usingheader; expires=$exptime; path=/");
```

But this doesn't work and just sets a **session** cookie.
The same thing works fine with **setcookie()** function

```
setcookie("__try2", "usingsetcookie", $exptime, '/');
```

The response headers are as below:

```
Set-Cookie: __try1=usingheader; expires=1613126399; path=/
Set-Cookie: __try2=usingsetcookie; expires=Fri, 12-Feb-2021 10:39:59 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set-cookie expiration in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456820/set-cookie-expiration-in-seconds)

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "a session cookie"?

Comment: @NicoHaase [A cookie that is removed when the client shuts down](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#session_cookie).

Comment: @Ivar Thank you for your suggestion, it did answer my question. Looks like there is another way to do it (since php v5.1.1 using DATE_COOKIE). I will update it as an answer here in case anyone finds it useful in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper time format for the expires flag is something like this `Tue, 19 Jan 2021 15:40:59 GMT`. We can generate this format using `gmdate()`. Below is an example to set the expiry time to 6 months from the current time.

```
$expirytime = gmdate("D, d-M-Y H:i:s T", strtotime( '+6 months' ));
```

or since  PHP 5.1.1 we can use the below. See [reference](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/docs/latest/PHP_Compat/_PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3---Compat---Constant---DATE.php.html).

```
echo gmdate(DATE_COOKIE , strtotime( '+6 months' ));
```